# Expired 2016 RC No Backups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have an expired version of SQL Server 2016 RC2 with SSRS installed as well.
The developer decided he didn’t get all the RDL from the SSRS before it expired and now needs to recover those.
I tried to run the installation to upgrade it, but it fails because the services are not started.
I tried to run the Edition Upgrade and it only upgrades a few components of which is not the engine.

How can I recover this?  When the developer installed and configured SSRS they did not save the encryption key, so I don’t believe I can do a new install and restore the mdf.  Is there anything else I can do.

Comment: The encryption key should only really hit you with data source connections and subscriptions. Any other data you should be fine when the database is attached to another machine.

Answer (score 2):

The correct procedure when you cannot start the SQL Server services on a computer (for whatever reason), is to simply copy all the database files to a working server and [attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15) them there.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar kind of fiasco at my workplace where the developers testing out the 2016 community preview version then decided to do their actual work off of there. We tried upgrading it to a legitimate version and it did not work. I had to involve my senior DBA and he said that he had to change the system clock and make it go back so the SQL Server was not expired. We were then able to get the necessary stuff off of that server.